# jquery and fold effect: hide directly without animation

Tags: jquery, hide, fold

I'm trying to animate a div, which has 3-4 child divs, with the `fold` effect:

```
$("#main div").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).effect('fold',{},'2000',callback);
    })
});
```

When I click on the main div it will normally disappear with a nice effect. But in fact, no, it only disappears.

[Here is a link](http://nyam.eclecticshots.org/test/) where you can see what happens (I use firefox) — ([link](http://nyam.eclecticshots.org/test/))

Answer (score 0):

To use the `effect` animation you have to include the jQuery UI library, or at least the parts relating to animation, as the basic jQuery library only has `linear` and `swing`:

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the [jQuery UI suite](http://jqueryui.com/).

(Quoted from: http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

To download just the effects (the 'easing' animations), you can visit: [jQuery UI's download page](http://jqueryui.com/download), and select only the 'effects' components.

Comment: i try to do as you recomend, but nothing happens, juste always the same thing : the div just disappear !!!
cause in fact, there was already the jquery-ui library loaded... else firebug say "effect is not a function"

Comment: i've try, but not work!! when you go on my link does it reproduced the problem or is there an animation?